# orthogonal complement of subspace w = {p(t) $\in P_2$, p(1)=0}

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is:

Given the space $P_2$ (space of all polynomials of degree $\leqslant 2)$. Let w = {p(t) $\in P_2$, p(1)=0} be a subspace of W. Find $W^\bot$

What i have so far.

Basis = {$t^2-1$,t-1}

let x = ($x_1,x_2,x_3$) be in $W^\bot$

$<x,a>$ = $-x_1+x_3=0$

$<x,b>$ = $-x_1+x_2=0$

So A = $$
        \begin{matrix}
        -1 & 0 & 1 \\
        -1 & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

then from there i found the row null space and got

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        1  \\
        1  \\
        1  \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

which i'm assuming is 
$W^\bot$

i'm probably totally wrong tough

Comment: You have to specify what is the inner product.

Comment: updated. idk if that helps.

Comment: You still haven’t explained what it means for two polynomials to be orthogonal.